# Pinging between two different vm's with different subnet on same host

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, ping

I am running a windows machine and i am running virtualbox on it

I have two VM's for cent os.

I want the two VM's to ping each other but they should have different subnets.

I am not really sure how to do it thus posting this question. I am really not concerned if they can connect to the internet or not, i want them in different subnets.

I tried by using two different internal networks but was not able to ping.

Thanks for you help in advance, really appreciate it

Comment: Rule #1 of virtualisation: *Nothing magical happened because someone said virtualisation*. In order for routing to take place between two different subnets you still need a router of some kind. There are a few virtual options out there so this shouldn't be too painful.

Answer (score 1):

If you have both boxes on different subnets inside your VM set they may never talk. The subnets being different are they both using the same gateway? Are they being NAT'd. Your question needs more information in order to better assist you.

A layer 3 switch would allow for this but you would need to either have a VM switch or you would need dedicated NICs going to a physical switch that would allow for individual ports to be configured.

Not understanding why you want them on different subnets. Prove they will function in your VM world by putting them both on the same subnet/gateway then work your way out. In this case you are using VLANs that never see/talk to one another.